# Duplex Printing - Adobe Livecycle

Tags: javascript, adobe, livecycle, livecycle-designer, xdp-pdf

I'm designing an XDP template in adobe livecycle desinger and i've below logic in layout:ready event to make a blank page visible if the total no of pages during layout ready event is odd number. sometimes this logic is misfiring, as a result i'm ending up with an odd number document, which is a big issue during printing! am i doing something wrong here? am i supposed to put this logic in layout:ready event? any input is greatly appreciated! Thank you!!

```
if(xfa.layout.pageCount() % 2 != 0)
    BlankPage.presence = "visible";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an [Adobe recommended way](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/11.0/DesignForms/WS624e3cba99b79e12-5cbb1ce513244559a7e-7ffb.2.html) to handle [duplexed printing](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/11.0/DesignForms/WS624e3cba99b79e12-5cbb1ce513244559a7e-7ffd.2.html) that doesn't involve scripting.

Comment: Hey Rob, thank you so much for the response. I'm trying to implement the suggestions you have made but i'm stuck at one point, I've configured a page to print only on odd page under pagination tab but when i tried to test the xdp on streamserve i got this error "XFAOUT: While loading XFA template: Invalid enumerated value: pageOdd" The logic works just fine while i preview the pdf in livecycle. Do you happen to know why this would occur? Please advise.

Comment: That's interesting...  I'm afraid that I'm not as familiar with the Production Printing module.  It is licensed from Streamserve.  Essentially, they convert the XDP over to the Streamserve format and then process it.  I am betting from the error message that there is some problem in the conversion process.  
I would contact Adobe technical support.  Since you're now doing things the way they recommend, they should be able to help you get it working.